# Matching "chrome-extension://*/" in Match Patterns

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Using `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener` one can specify a `requestFilter = { urls: ["<all_urls>"] };` as a second parameter

Listening to the traffic I get this whenever I do a fetch from my extension
`{frameId: 0, initiator: "chrome-extension://abcdef" }`

While I can capture the `chrome-extension` schema with the `<all_url>` filter. I only want to match it with `const requestFilter = { urls: ["chrome-extension://*/"] };`

This doesn't work and I can't find anything about  `chrome-extension` in schemas under the docs at https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/match_patterns/

However it says that `The special pattern <all_urls> matches any URL that starts with a permitted scheme`. So it appears to be permitted but I can't make it work. I'd appreciate any help of pointers in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These aren't really network requests so there are no headers event. Instead you can listen to `onBeforeRequest` event and to capture all extension URLs add another `*` so it looks like `"chrome-extension://*/*"`

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(console.log, {
  urls: ["chrome-extension://*/*"],
});
```